# python download from Sharepoint

Tags: python, sharepoint, download, python-requests

my task is to write a python program which downloads a couple of pictures from Sharepoint from  given urls, at first I am trying with one pic. My idea is that first I authenticate myself, then download the pic.
Didnt find any similar tutorial, tired to do it based on an upload turorial, this is what I have so far:

```
from shareplum import Office365
import requests

authcookie = Office365(share_point_site='example.sharepoint.com', username='example', password='example')
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies = authcookie
session.headers.update({'user-agent': 'doesnt_matter'})
session.headers.update({'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'})

url='the given url'

with requests.get(url, headers={'X-RequestDigest': 'FormDigestValue'}) as resp:

    resp.raise_for_status()
```

At this point im getting: `raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url:`
but I am sure my credentials are right. Any idea how to do this?